# TypeError issue when combining two if statements

Tags: python, if-statement, typeerror

I'm trying to create an if-else statement that provides the mean if given integers or floats and the mode if given strings. I can get it to work if I run two if statements separately but if I combine them, I get:

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'

Here is an example:

```
data =  [['a',20],
 ['b',20],
 ['c',30],
 ['b',30],
 ['d',25]]

column = 1
if type(data[0][column] == int) or type(data[0][column] == float):
    mean_mode = 0
    for row in data:
        mean_mode += row[column]/len(data)
```

Here mean_mode = 25 like it should

```
column = 0
if type(data[0][column] == str):
    string_list = []
    for row in data:
        string_list.append(row[column])

    mean_mode = max(set(string_list), key = string_list.count)
```

Here mean_mode = 'b' like it should

But when I combine them, I get the TypeError described above

```
column = 0
if type(data[0][column] == int) or type(data[0][column] == float):
    mean_mode = 0
    for row in data:
        mean_mode += row[column]/len(data)
else:
    string_list = []
    for row in data:
        string_list.append(row[column])

    mean_mode = max(set(string_list), key = string_list.count)
```

How can I get this to work in 1 if-else statement?

Comment: `== int` should not be inside the parentheses.

Comment: `type(data[0][column]) == int`

Comment: And the same with `== float`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your parentheses are wrong:

```
if type(data[0][column] == int)
```

You need to look up the type of the first column entry; compare *that* to `int`:

```
if type(data[0][column]) == int
```

Also, you might want use the built-in routine:

```
if isint(data[0][column]) or ...
```

Answer (score 1):

What is wrong is that the the parentheses in the condition of the if-statement is misplaced. The correct condition would be:

```py
if type(data[0][column]) == int or type(data[0][column]) == float:
    ...
```

So what is going on in the condition with the misplaced parentheses? Both `type(data[0][column] == int)` and `type(data[0][column] == float)` evaluates to either `type(True)` or `type(False)` which again evaluates to `<class 'bool'>`, i.e. the class of `True` and `False`.

The if-statement implicitly calls bool on the condition, i.e. `bool(<class 'bool'> or <class 'bool'>` which evaluates to `bool(<class 'bool'>)` and finally `True`. And there you have it. The problem is that the condition of the if-statement is always `True`